# Need help in appending dictionary items in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to get movies by genres from tmdb movie dataset by converting it into json.

There should be multiple entries for a specific genre like 'adventure', but all i get to see is the last record and seems like the previous records are getting overwritten. I have verified this by adding a print statement in the if statement and the details are showing up in the console but somehow getting overwritten.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
final_list = []
for i in range(1,1000):
        if genre_name in data[str(i)]['genres']:
            movie_dict["Title"] = data[str(i)]['title']
            movie_dict["Language"] = data[str(i)]['original_language']
            final_list = [movie_dict]
    return final_list
```

Comment: You want to append data to the list, not redefine the list. Change `final_list = [movie_dict]` to `final_list.append(movie_dict)`. Then you have to fix the indentation. At the moment you return in the first cycle of the loop. And last but not least: You have to redefine the dictionary `movie_dict` at the beginning of each loop.

Comment: I did already try with append and correct indentation but the last line but not the least to declare the movie_dict in the beginning of the loop worked for me. Thanks for saving the day. If you can add it as an answer then i can upvote it as helpful.

Comment: I added an answer with an explanation and possible optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two obvious problems. You redefine `final_list` in the loop and you return during the first loop.

Fixing that will give you something like this:

```
def myfunction(data, genre_name):
    movie_dict = {}
    final_list = []
    for i in range(1,1000):
        if genre_name in data[str(i)]['genres']:
            movie_dict["Title"] = data[str(i)]['title']
            movie_dict["Language"] = data[str(i)]['original_language']
            final_list.append(movie_dict)
    return final_list
```

Now there is another, more subtle problem. You always add the same dictionary to the list.

To give an example:

```
d = {}
l = []
for i in range(5):
    d['x'] = i ** 2
    l.append(d)
print(l)
```

Now `l` contains the same dictionary 5 times and this dictionary will have the content from the last iteration of the loop: `[{'x': 16}, {'x': 16}, {'x': 16}, {'x': 16}, {'x': 16}]`. To fix this you have to create the dictionary in the loop, so in your code you have to move `movie_dict = {}` to an appropriate place:

```
def myfunction(data, genre_name):
    final_list = []
    for i in range(1,1000):
        if genre_name in data[str(i)]['genres']:
            movie_dict = {}
            movie_dict["Title"] = data[str(i)]['title']
            movie_dict["Language"] = data[str(i)]['original_language']
            final_list.append(movie_dict)
    return final_list
```

---

Now some more advanced stuff. I assume `data` is a dictionary since you use a string for indexing. If you're not limited to 1000 entries but want to access all the values in the dictionary you can loop over the dictionaries values:

```
def myfunction(data, genre_name):
    final_list = []

    for entry in data.values():
        if genre_name in entry['genres']:
            movie_dict = {}
            movie_dict["Title"] = entry['title']
            movie_dict["Language"] = entry['original_language']
            final_list.append(movie_dict)
    return final_list
```

Now let us create the dictionary on the fly in the call to `append`.

```
def myfunction(data, genre_name):
    final_list = []

    for entry in data.values():
        if genre_name in entry['genres']:
            final_list.append({'Title': entry['title'], 'Language': entry['original_language']})
    return final_list
```

This can be rewritten as a list comprehension:

```
def myfunction(data, genre_name):
    return [{'Title': entry['title'], 'Language': entry['original_language']} for entry in data.values() if genre_name in entry['genres']]
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `final_list.append(movie_dict)`.

Answer (score 0):

Bro you were actually actually returning the list after each value was added try this way and it will not overwrite it. The main reason is that you were returning the list in the for loop and everytime the loop run it save new dictionary in the list and remove the old one

```
final_list = []
for i in range(1,1000):
        if genre_name in data[str(i)]['genres']:
            movie_dict["Title"] = data[str(i)]['title']
            movie_dict["Language"] = data[str(i)]['original_language']
            final_list.append(movie_dict)
return final_list
```